# How can I create a button with button with different pictures and information on it? (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, button

I'm making an application that integrates with Facebook Messenger right now, and I'm trying to make the screen that displays each individual conversation with people. An example would be this:

[image: Picture on the left, name of the person/other text fields to the right(in this case, name is "Just You").]

I apologize for the white on white background, but a button looking something like this is what I'm looking for (This is taken from the Facebook Messenger app). I can't figure out a way to create a button that has fields for a variable picture. I've crawled the web for hours trying to find something, but could only find resources to make an image an entire button, and not one that would encapsulate both an image and text.

Does anybody know how this procedure is done, or know of a good source to learn from? I feel like it's simple and I'm overlooking a key resource.

Comment: Umm.. If I really understand your question I'd suggest to use a custom list and add onItemClickListener()..

Answer (score 0):

With this library you can create circle image 
https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

And create your own component 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/component/android-custom-components-example/

But in your case extends from RelativeLayout instead of TextView